# DropzoneJS As Part Of PHP Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I have this simplified situation :

```
<form action='process.php' method='post'>

<div class="dropzone no-margin">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
    </div>
</div>

</form>

$(".dropzone").dropzone({ 
url: "/test2.php",
maxFilesize: 2,
maxFiles: 5
});
```

`test2.php` works just fine, it upload files dropped on the dropzone immediately. but, the problem is, I need to pass those file names of uploaded files to the form as hidden text input.

here's `test2.php` looks like :

```
<?php
$target_dir = "user/product/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

I'm a beginner in javascript or jquery world. So, I really need your help to give me a clue how to pass the file names to the form as hidden text input so it can be written into database later on.

thank you so much and I really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

there is method in Dropzone i.e **sending** that will use to send data before file is sent.if multiple files are uploaded then use **sendingmultiple** method.

```
$(".dropzone").dropzone({ 
   url: "/test2.php",
   maxFilesize: 2,
   maxFiles: 5,
   sending:function (data, xhr, formdata) {
      console.log("data :",data);
      //here you can get file name from data variable.you can add that to your form by following line.
      formdata.append('hidden field name', 'file name');
      //you can add as much parameter you want to pass to your post data by formdata.append() function. That will add data to your form data.you can refer that value by using $_POST['hidden_field_name'] at PHP side.
    }
});
```

Please check following link for detail :

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events